# Why national (Polish) characters don't show in bash in screen over serial tty?

Tags: linux, bash, locale

We have remote login via tty to device using screen application.
When i press national key combination i get only screen flash and no output. 
But when i start my own written simple application in the same bash console i get:

```
root#0000:~# ./charcode 
ł
Got char c: C5
Got char c: 82
Got char c: 0A
^C
root#0000:~#
```

And after that when i do:

```
root#0000:~# echo -e '\xC5\x82'
ł
root#0000:~#
```

The source code of the simple application is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        printf("Got char c: %02X\n", (unsigned char)c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Why national (Polish) characters don't show in bash?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Debian and all its derivatives (eg. ubuntu and others)
Look [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=818065).

To fix this bug:

```
rm /etc/console-setup/*.gz && setupcon --save-only
```

This will do a change in the buggy line under

```
/etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh
-loadkeys '/tmp/tmpkbd.iDWdSi' > '/dev/null'
+loadkeys '/etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz' > '/dev/null'
```

Comment: Seems to be fixed here ... (Devuan, so I guess it'll be fixed in Debian, too).